# Lost minionpro font after migrating from latex 2014 to latex 2017

Tags: fonts, minionpro, texlive-2017

I have osx el capitan 10.11.6, and I recently updated from latex 2014 to latex 2017. I found that my  minionpro font in stalled under 2014 do not compile anymore. I remember that getting this font was pretty tough to do the last time. If there an easy way to migrate the installed font so that it can work with 2017 now, or do I need to reinstall it from scratch by downloading the font and installing it? Otherwise, it is possible to point my TexShop (that is what I use to compile) to the 2014 release of latex with the idea that it will be able to compile the minionpro font successfully from there?

Comment: If you still have all the files from the 2014 installation you can copy them over. Perhaps (if you put them in your texmf-local or texmfhome tree) there are already there and you only need to activate the map file).

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply. I sitll have all the file from the 2014 installation. I'm looking for some guidance in what to copy over. I remember when I installed the font, there was a lot of files moved over  to get that to work. I'm a little hesitant on making copyovers without knowing what I need to copy over.

Comment: My crystal ball is on holiday. So I have no idea what files you have and where they are.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think it's a good idea to deliver snarky comments to new users. How about telling them what they need to inform us about before we can help further?

Comment: @Sverre This is not a question from a new user. He/she is using tex for at least three years and even managed to install minion pro. I'm expecting from such users to provide some senseful info without me having to beg them or do some basic introduction into the file system of their tex system.

Comment: Sorry to annoy. I'm not that familiar with the file system. From the first comment, I thought there might be some standard structure in installations, or perhaps some standard files. Alternatively, I figured it could require an install from scratch like before. I surmised from the second comment that things could vary a lot installation to installation. I suppose when I'm a bit better at this, I'll know the difference of what needs a proper install to work vs, a copy over of old files. I did manage to get the font installed before, but the answer to that last question wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you how they're organised on my MiKTeX system:

- `.enc` files are in `texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/`,
- `MinionPro.map` is in `texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/MinionPro/`,
- `.otf` files are in `texmf-local/fonts/adobe/MinionPro/`,
- `.tfm` files are in `texmf-local/fonts/adobe/MinionPro/`,
- `.pfb` files are in `texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/`,
- `.vf` files are in `texmf-local/fonts/vf/adobe/MinionPro/`,
- `.fd` and `.sty` files are in `texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/`.

I hope this helps.